# Why does such statement work in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm using MySQL 5.6.23-enterprise-commercial-advanced. I have a table called `FILE` as:

```
+---------+
| file_id |
+---------+
|      11 |
|      12 |
|      13 |
|      14 |
+---------+
```

I try to run a query of `SELECT A.FILE_ID FROM FILE A;` under **root@localhost**, and it is successfully executed. But there is no such table as **A**(any will work).So why it can be executed and seemingly have the same effect as `SELECT FILE.ID FROM FILE;`? I'm working on an existing project, and I have seen this. Is there any benefit of using it?

Comment: Perhaps you should start with a tutorial on SQL. Table aliasing is one of the simplest concepts. In fact, there are cases where you have to alias tables, eg when you want to use the same table twice in a query

Comment: `SELECT A.FILE_ID FROM FILE A` is the same as `SELECT A.FILE_ID FROM FILE as A` - the 'as', which introduces an *alias*, can be omitted in some cases. That should help you find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're giving the table an alias of `A` so you're essentially temporarily renaming the table during the select statement.

See link for more information -  [MYSQL ALIAS](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/)

Answer (score 1):

`A` is only an alias for table file in your case. That is why your query works.

Read [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) for more information about aliases in SQL:

> SQL aliases are used to temporarily rename a table or a column heading.

Answer (score 1):

Your table name is `FILE` and `A` is the alias name of your table `FILE`.

You can read using Alias in select statement:

[MySQL Alias](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Aliases are used to temporarily rename a table or column name for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

In your case `A` as alias of table. So you must need to write `as` between  `FILE` and `A`. So now your query is like this

```
SELECT A.FILE_ID FROM FILE as A;
```